# match on two ADTs

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have two ADT structures.

```
trait Values[_] {}
case class StringV(values: List[String]) extends Values[String]
case class NumberV(values: List[Double]) extends Values[Double]
// and a few more
trait Filter[_] {}
case class StringFilter(values: Set[String]) extends Filter[String]
case class NumberFilter(lower: Double, upper: Double) extends Filter[Double]
// and a few more
```

Given two variables

```
val v: Values[_]
val f: Filter[_]
```

How can I check if they have the same type at runtime, and recover if
they do not? Pattern matching doesn't work.

```
(v, f) match {
  case (v: Values[A], f: Filter[A]) forSome { type A } => 
}
```

The brute force solution would be

```
def typecheck(v: Values[_], f: Filter[_]):
  Option[(Values[A], Filter[A]) forSome { type A }] =
  (v, f) match {
    case v: StringV => f match {
      case f: StringFilter => Some(v, f)
      case _ => None
    }
    case v: NumberV => f match {
      case f: NumberFilter => Some(v, f)
      case _ => None
    }
  }
```

Is there a better solution than simply typing everything out?

EDIT:

I'd prefer to have the tuple `(v, f)` conform to the type `(Values[A], ParamFilterConfig[A]) forSome { type A }`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `typeOf` from the reflection API :

```
import reflect.runtime.universe._

def valueAndFilter[V: TypeTag, F: TypeTag](v: Values[V], f: Filter[F]) =
  if (typeOf[V] =:= typeOf[F]) Some(v, f) else None

valueAndFilter(NumberV(1 :: Nil), NumberFilter(1d, 2d))
// Some((NumberV(List(1.0)),NumberFilter(1.0,2.0)))
valueAndFilter(StringV(Nil), NumberFilter(1d, 2d))
// None
```

You could also check at compile time by requesting implicit evidence that the types of `Values` and `Filter` are equal.

```
def valueAndFilter2[V, F](v: Values[V], f: Filter[F])(implicit ev: V =:= F) = (v, f)

valueAndFilter2(NumberV(1 :: Nil), NumberFilter(1d, 2d))
// (NumberV(List(1.0)),NumberFilter(1.0,2.0))
valueAndFilter2(StringV(Nil), NumberFilter(1d, 2d))
// error: Cannot prove that String =:= Double.
```

Comment: Is that possible with the added `(Values[A], ParamFilterConfig[A]) forSome { type A }` signature?

Comment: I don't understand why you want to return an existential type.

Comment: Me neither. I'll take another approach instead.